# Does Windows Azure support the SPDY protocol?

Tags: azure, spdy

does anyone know if Windows Azure does (or plan to) support the SPDY protocol? I didn't find anything so I guess it is not supported yet...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Two answers:

1) To support SPDY, the HTTP/HTTPS load balancers must support NPN negotiation as part of the SSL handshake. I don't believe the existing LB's have support for this, hence you won't be able to use the platform LB's.

2) If you configure the load balancers as simple TCP proxies, and push the SSL negotiation down to your app servers, then you can deploy an app server which can perform NPN negotiation (for example, Apache with mod_spdy, or node-spdy, etc).

Same strategy applies for AWS as well.

Answer (score 6):

Just thought I would add a link to the feature request made for SPDY support on Azure.

http://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-websites/suggestions/3554797-spydy

From the Azure team - It is planned but will take a long time to implement.

Comment: I might add that Google is now dropping its SPDY development and is going with HTTP2. I suspect that Azure might take this rotue as well and that SPDY will not be implemented, if it hasn't already.